# Need some help with articles in a simple list (please see the actual example below)

Tags: articles, lists, headline-english

This is the list of topics and their tasks. Do I need to put articles in the following cases?

1. **THE** meeting:

- Discuss achievements
- Find solutions

2. **THE** brand's problem

- Find the strategy
- Set tasks

In general, is it necessary to put articles in headlines or names of list items/clauses when there isn't a full sentence. Example:

**The** Insight
 Some description

I'd be extremely grateful for any help.

Comment: ......................No.

Comment: Could you give any reason or explanation?

Comment: Below sentence level, and especially with headlines / labels / chapter headings ... , regular grammar does not apply. It's not 'anything goes', but largely style preference, and one gets more savvy about what works with experience. FWIW, I'd not put an article with Meeting or Insight but would with The brand's problem here (it seems less of a pure title, heading more towards an intro).

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. Thank you very much.